# mock function with return mock value in jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, typescript2.0

I use react-redux to create a middleware and would like to write some test for it. How can I mock the return from helper function `checkNumberHistory` so I can test the logic that `if` blocked ?

```
import {checkNumberHistory} from '@src/helper';

export const middlewareAction = (): AppThunk => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const recordededNumber = getState()?.recordedNumber || 0;
    const strNumber = getState()?.strNumber || 0;
    const isNumberChanged = checkNumberHistory(recordededNumber, strNumber);

    if (isNumberChanged) {
      dispatch(setNumber(strNumber));
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you show where `checkNumberHistory` is defined and how it's imported into the middleware?

Comment: updated it is just a export function from another file

Comment: Is the function deterministic? You can definitely mock the import by my instinct would be to try _not_ to mock it and then your test also tests that function

Comment: i prefer not to test that function. as it is the unit test. i want to isolate the test and the logic of `checkNumberHistory ` has been test other place already

Comment: or i can mock `getState()?.recordedNumber` and `getState()?.strNumber`

Comment: Yeah, I would personally be mocking the state object

Comment: thank you. i will try to mock the state object then

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `jest.mock` to mock the `checkNumberHistory` import. The following shows using the *actual* values for other named imports and mocking `checkNumberHistory`:

```js
jest.mock('@src/helper', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@src/helper'),
  checkNumberHistory: () => 'Some mocked return value',
}));

describe('middleware tests', () => {
  it('does something', () => {
    // test here
  });
});
```

As mentioned in my comment, I tend to try not to mock helper functions if I don't have to (i.e., if they're deterministic).